# node js and passport validation miss passport session

Tags: mongodb, nodes, passport.js

I have **app.js** as below

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyparser = require('body-parser'),
    db = require('./model/db');
var app=express();
var dbConfig = require('./db.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.createConnection(dbConfig.url);
var passport = require('passport');

    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
    }));
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'crackalackin',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : { secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }, // 4 hours
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
 // and displaying in templates
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
        app.listen(6061,function(){
    console.log("started on port 6061");
});
```

**/passport/init.js**

```
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function (passport) {

    // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        try {
            User.getById(id, function (err, user) {
                done(err, user);
            });
        } catch (ex) {

        }
    });

    // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
    login(passport);
    signup(passport);

}
```

when I write `console.log(req.session)` in /passport/login.js at validation function.

I get **output** like

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-02-01T14:10:38.523Z,
     originalMaxAge: 14400000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false } }
```

I miss the

```
passport: {}
```

so I can login but can not generate passport session.

So **isAuthenticated** function say **"login plase"**.
how can I manage session here.

Comment: what's in `./passport/init`?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ I have added passport.init file in question

Comment: where is `getById` from. Does mongoose have a method like that. I know there is a  `Model.findById() `

Comment: let me try it .

Comment: @jackblank
done but do not work